# Why should a java capturing lambda be re-evaluated every time it is encountering if it can capture only effectively final variables?

Tags: java-8, lambda

I read that a capturing lambda will be evaluated every time it is encountered. However, it can capture only an effectively final variable. So, what is the need to reevaluating such a lambda?

Comment: Did you mean *everytime* instead of *everything*? And can you quote your source please?

Comment: And give an example of what you mean, please.

Comment: I think the answer is that side-effects in lambdas are allowed, and hence Java lambdas are not guaranteed to be pure functions. On another note, it is not quite clear what you mean with "encountered" and "evaluated".

Answer (score 0):

A local variable being effectively final means that that instance of the variable does not change. That does not mean that when you run the code again (e.g. in another run of the function, or another run of the loop containing the variable) where you have a new instance of that variable, that it will be the same as the previous instance of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The final variable will point to the same object, but that object can change internally, so the result of the lambda expression can be different.

Answer (score -1):

as an example, the variable `this` is effectively final, but fields of `this` can change, hence the need to reevaluate the lambda. you cannot guarantee that the fields (or states) are identical everytime you encounter a lambda.